# Retrieve specific files under a directory in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to see the list of specific files under the directory using linux.
Say for example:- 
I have following sub-directories in my current directory

```
 Feb 16 00:37 a1
 Feb 16 00:38 a2
 Feb 16 00:36 a3
```

Now if i do `ls a* -` I can see

```
bash-4.1$ ls a*
a:

a1:
123.sh  123.txt

a2:
a234.sh  a234.txt

a3:
a345.sh  a345.txt
```

I want to filter out only `.sh` files from the directory so that output should be:-

```
a1:
123.sh

a2:
a234.sh

a3:
a345.sh
```

Is it Possible?

Moreover is it possible to print the 1st line of sh file also?

Answer (score 2):

The following `find` command should work for you:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -path '*/a*/*.sh' -print -exec head -n1 {} \;
```

Comment: Can I only get output in the form of:-  a1:
123.sh

a2:
a234.sh

a3:
a345.sh

Comment: I want to put some filter like grep or sed with ls a*... is it possible something like ls *a | find... Please suggest

Comment: You want to apply that filter to the first line of those files?

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at those options. I hope you would find what you you are looking for

### basic 'find file' commands

```
find / -name foo.txt -type f -print             # full command
find / -name foo.txt -type f                    # -print isn't necessary
find / -name foo.txt                            # don't have to specify "type==file"
find . -name foo.txt                            # search under the current dir
find . -name "foo.*"                            # wildcard
find . -name "*.txt"                            # wildcard
find /users/al -name Cookbook -type d           # search '/users/al'
```

### search multiple dirs

```
find /opt /usr /var -name foo.scala -type f     # search multiple dirs
```

### case-insensitive searching

```
find . -iname foo                               # find foo, Foo, FOo, FOO, etc.
find . -iname foo -type d                       # same thing, but only dirs
find . -iname foo -type f                       # same thing, but only files
```

### find files with different extensions

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.sh" \)                       # *.c and *.sh files
find . -type f \( -name "*cache" -o -name "*xml" -o -name "*html" \)   # three patterns
```

### find files that don't match a pattern (-not)

```
find . -type f -not -name "*.html"     # find allfiles not ending in ".html"
```

### find files by text in the file (find + grep)

```
find . -type f -name "*.java" -exec grep -l StringBuffer {} \;    # find StringBuffer in all *.java files
find . -type f -name "*.java" -exec grep -il string {} \;         # ignore case with -i option
find . -type f -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep 'GET /foo' {} \;          # search for a string in gzip'd files
```

Answer (score 0):

Only using `ls`, you can get the .sh files and their parent directory with:

```
ls -1 * | grep ":\|.sh" | grep -B1 .sh
```

Which will provide the output:

```
a1:
123.sh
a2:
a234.sh
a3:
a345.sh
```

However, note that this won't have the correct behavior in case of you have any file called for example `123.sh.txt`

In order to print the first line of the first .sh file in every folder:

```
head -n1 $(ls -1 */*.sh)
```

Comment: Ok thanks for this but if some directory does not have .sh then also it is listing how to remove those directories?

Comment: @NVTechie Then you can grep again just to have the previous line (the line which has the directory name) to every .sh file. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** and very easy and simple just with `ls` itself:

`ls -d */*.sh`

**Prove**

[image]

---

If you would like to print it with newline:

```
t $  ls -d */*.sh | tr ' ' '\n'
d1/file.sh                                                                                          
d2/file.sh                                                                                          
d3/file.sh
```

**Or**
`ls -d */*.sh | tr '/' '\n'`
the output:

```
d1
file.sh
d2
file.sh
d3
file.sh
```

---

Also for the first line if you want:

```
t $ ls -d */*.sh | tr ' ' '\n' | head -n 1
d1/file.sh
```